# Codeigniter - transacciones stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb

Es posible?, funcionan como debe? hacer transacciones invocando store procedure desde query builder?, es decir se revierten los cambios con rollback en caso de error?, gracias.

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('call sp_uno()');
$this->db->query('call sp_dos()');
$this->db->query('call sp_tres()');
$this->db->trans_complete(); 

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('OTRA QUERY...');
$this->db->query('OTRA QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}else{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

1. Utilizas `$this->db->trans_begin();` para comenzar la transacción.
2. Realizas las consultas.
3. Verificas el estado de la transacción usando `$this->db->trans_status();`.
4. Si el `Status` es `TRUE`lo confirmas utilizando `$this->db->trans_commit();`.
5. Si el `Status` es `FALSE` lo anulas utilizando `$this->db->trans_rollback();`.

> Básicamente esta es una transacción manual, pero Tradicionalmente, las
>   transacciones han requerido una buena cantidad de trabajo para su
>   implementación, ya que exigen que usted realice un seguimiento de sus
>   consultas y determine si debe comprometerse o retroceder en función
>   del éxito o el fracaso de sus consultas. Esto es particularmente
>   incómodo en el caso de las consultas anidadas. Por el contrario, se
>   implemento un sistema inteligente de transacciones que hace todo esto
>   por usted automáticamente (también puede administrar sus transacciones
>   manualmente si así lo desea, pero en realidad no hay ningún
>   beneficio).

Referencia: [Codeigniter Transaction](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html)